# Obscure keyup event bug

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-events

I have a `keyup` event for whenever you type into a form, and it works perfectly for every key, except <kbd>d</kbd>. If I press any key, that key gets detected, but the first <kbd>d</kbd> would not get detected. For instance, if I type <kbd>d</kbd>, the <kbd>d</kbd> will not get detected, but if I type <kbd>d</kbd>, the second <kbd>d</kbd> will get detected.

Simple demo:

```
$(".navbar-form").on("keyup", function (data) {

  var text = $('.form-control')[0].value;
  $.ajax({
    url: '/users/search',
    type: 'GET',
    data: {text: text},
    success: function(responseData) {
      //do what you plan to do with data
    }
  });
})
```

Comment: Have you tried it with multiple keyboards?

Comment: I have not. I don't think it is the keyboard. My keyboard clearly has a functioning d from my ability to type this, and the second d gets detected.

Comment: @David: what kind of help you're looking for? You haven't provided a demo or even code. Was your question about some special magic around "d"? Well, it's a regular character, without any special properties.

Comment: That's precisely why I'm confused. I don't know why it isn't working. I suppose my question is about why it isn't working as intended.

Comment: note that neither your post nor your post title contain a question. Did you actually need help with anything?

Comment: @David The point is that you need to provide code, otherwise this question is pointless. We can't guess why it wouldn't work because it works fine everywhere else, so it's something with your code.

Comment: "why it isn't working as intended" --- that's an easy question then. "Because you've made a mistake somewhere". Here you go.

Comment: I posted the relevant code.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/SEBja/ - your relevant code works fine. Please spend some time and create a demo on jsfiddle that demonstrates the issue. PS: I'm sure you'll find out the issue during the process of simplification your real code oto run on jsfiddle

Comment: Are you sure there isn't any code anywhere (inlcuding libraries) that might be testing for key events?

Comment: @Jeffman if there is any code anywhere testing for key events, I didn't write it and I don't know where I would find it.

Comment: @zerkms you managed to get an ajax request sent for simply typing `d`?

Comment: @David: as you could see on my jsfiddle - I used `console.log()` to see the data. In `$.ajax()` result would be exactly the same.

Comment: The title of the question `Obscure keyup event bug` doesn't match with your code, what is it ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You either:

a. Have a bad keyboard,

b. Have some external code from some library or somewhere else in
   your page or application that is catching a d keypress and preventing
   the event from bubbling.

So,

1. It **certainly** has nothing to do with the code you posted (see zerkms' comment), and
2. If you want it resolved, you will either have to post more code, or start debugging the code we cannot see. Do a process of elemination. Delete everything else in your page. Does it still not work? Play around. You won't get any more insight here with what you have posted.